# How to automatically active a modal when loading a page?

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I wonder how during a redirection, I can redirect in a page with a modal already active.

What I have tried

```
<h2>Example of creating Modals with Twitter Bootstrap</h2>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-backdrop="show"> Launch demo modal </button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times; </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> This Modal title
```

Comment: Your was hidden due to improper indentation.I've edited for you.Accept the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
$('.myModal').modal('show')
```

dont forgot to include bootstrap JS ..

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

version may be based on your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Can you use javascript/jquery?

If you can use them you could make a script run after the page loads with something along the lines of

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```